# Every ~2 weeks - Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I came across a very weird error with Facebook login on one of my production web application.

For my app, currently in production, when I try to do Facebook login it kept promoting the user with "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."...

The strange thing is that it used to work. This error will show up after around 2 weeks and I have to reset the app secret key in order for it to work again for ~ 2 weeks more. This cycle have been going on for like 4 times already.

The other environments I used to test / stage for this app have no issue with the secret they were assigned with and have been working solidly for over 4 months.

Comment: If resetting the app secret resolves the issue, that sounds like it is a bug on Facebook's part. I recommend that you file a bug report about it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs. Make sure to include all details needed for Facebook to fully reproduce the issue (i.e. include all URLs in full).

Comment: thanks. will follow up on that.